# Pear Mail function not sending Email

Tags: php, apache, email, pear

I have a problem with the following code, and I cannot figure it out.

I'm using this bit of code with the VALID values, but it does NOT send any email to the recipient...

```
<?php
include("Mail.php");
/* mail setup recipients, subject etc */
$recipients = "feedback@yourdot.com";
$headers["From"] = "user@somewhere.com";
$headers["To"] = "feedback@yourdot.com";
$headers["Subject"] = "User feedback";
$mailmsg = "Hello, This is a test.";
/* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
$smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.mycorp.com";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = "smtpusername";
$smtpinfo["password"] = "smtpPassword";
/* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
$mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
/* Ok send mail */
$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);
?>
```

Can anyone help me why isn't it sending email, or what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the recipient server isn't filtering it out?

Comment: does mail works? are the smtp connection settings OK? Does the script has a debug function?

Comment: Do you have access to the server log files? try tail the /var/log/maillog